# How to solve this equation containing $P(n,r$)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$P(n,r) := \frac{n!}{ (n-r)!}$

The equation is:

$P(n,r) = 42 P(n,3)$

I need to clear the variable $n$. It doesn't matter that it has to be expressed as a function of $r$.

I cannot pass the step:

$(n-3)! = 42(n-r)!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $P(n,3)=n(n-1)(n-2)$, and $P(n,r)=n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-r+1)$, so you’re being asked to solve the equation

$$n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(n-r+1)=42n(n-1)(n-2)\;.$$

Do the obvious cancellation, and then try to express $42$ as a product of consecutive integers. (Note that this can be done in more than one way.)

Comment: Further hint: $42 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 7$.  This implies that there are exactly two possible answers (where $n,r\in\mathbb{N}$)